# in-browser transformation issue for really long String

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a really long string stored in a property file, It serves as a tool tip for a button on my webpage.

Problem: I use the property file in my xhtml, the key gets evaluated to that long string but it gets broken in multiple string with new line so the browser issues an error like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Because it's evaluated as following:

```
function addTooltipForm1() {
        var idsof = [ "Form 5558", "Automatic Extension", "DFVC Program", "Special Extension" ];
        var tipTexts = ["Select this if you have filed an extension of time 
to file form 5500 with the IRS using the completed Form 
5558. (Employer should maintain a copy of the form 5558 with the filer’s record)."
}
```

In code what I've written it with key in EL as:

```
function addTooltipForm1() {
        var idsof = [ "Form 5558", "Automatic Extension", "DFVC Program", "Special Extension" ];
        var tipTexts = ["#{helpText5500['5500.identificationInformation.helpText.5558Form']}"];
        addTooltipToEnums('#questionDOption', idsof, tipTexts);
     }
```

So apparently the key

```
#{helpText5500['5500.identificationInformation.helpText.5558Form']}
```

got converted into

```
    Select this if you have filed an extension of time 
to file form 5500 with the IRS using the completed Form
```

And that what gave error of unexpected token.

I've tried using template literals i.e. backticks (`) that works but not on safari and internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals for multi-line strings:

```js
let tipTexts = [`Select this if you have filed an extension of time 
to file form 5500 with the IRS using the completed Form 
5558. (Employer should maintain a copy of the form 5558 with the filer’s record).`]

console.log(tipTexts);
```

Comment: look at the last line of my question. Safari and IE don't support template literals.                                                                                                
    gives invalid character '`'